# What does librosa.load return?

Tags: python, signal-processing, librosa, audio-analysis

I'm working with the librosa library, and
I would like to know what information is returned by the `librosa.load` function when I read a audio (.wav) file.
Is it the instantaneous sound pressure in pa, or the just the instantaneous amplitude of the sound signal with no units?

Comment: It returns floating type audio time series. What is your main question ?

Comment: "I would like to know what is the information that is returned by librosa.load function when I read a audio(.wav) file using it. Is it the instantaneous sound pressure in pa? or the just the instantaneous amplitude of the sound signal with no unit? "

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To confirm the previous answer, librosa.load returns a time series that in [librosa glossary](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/LibROSA.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/glossary.html) is defined as:

"**time series**:
Typically an audio signal, denoted by *y*, and represented as a one-dimensional `numpy.ndarray` of floating-point values. *y[t]* corresponds to the amplitude of the waveform at sample *t*."

The amplitude is usually measured as a function of the change in pressure around the microphone or receiver device that originally picked up the audio. (See more [here](https://medium.com/comet-ml/applyingmachinelearningtoaudioanalysis-utm-source-kdnuggets11-19-e160b069e88)).

Comment: Excellent! This is the clarification I was looking for .

Comment: This wasn't easy to find. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 11):

According to my knowledge, the amplitude is the measurement of the change in atmospheric pressure while recording. According to `librosa.load` documentation [here](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.load.html#librosa.load), this method returns two things:

- The sample rate `sr`: which means how many samples are recorded per second.
- A 2D array:

  - **The first axis**: represents the recorded samples of amplitudes (change of air pressure) in the audio.
  - **The second axis**: represents the number of channels in the audio.

Here is an example from the official documentation:

```
>>> import librosa

>>> filename = librosa.util.example_audio_file()
>>> y, sr = librosa.load(filename)
>>> sr  #sample rate
22050
>>> y.shape   #mono (1 channel)
(1355168,)
>> y.shape[0] / sr  #duration of audio file in seconds
61.45886621315193
```

As we can see:

- The sample rate is `22050` which means that the recorder was recording `22050` times per second.
- The `y.shape = (1355168,)` which means that there were `1355168` samples recorded on just one channel (Mono) over the whole audio.
- Using simple math, you can calculate the duration of this audio file by dividing the `total_number_of_samples` over the `sample_rate`

### Added from comments

Do note that if you read the file as `y, sr = librosa.load(filename)`, librosa will resample the signal to `22050` Hz by default. As stated in the [documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.load.html?highlight=load#librosa.load), if you want to get the native sampling rate, you should read the signal as `y, sr = librosa.load(filename, sr=None)`.

Comment: Do note that if you read the file as `y, sr = librosa.load(filename)`, `librosa` will resample the signal to 22050 Hz by default. As stated in the [documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.load.html?highlight=load#librosa.load), if you want to get the native sampling rate, you should read the signal as `y, sr = librosa.load(filename, sr=None)`

Comment: thx @ArturoMoncada-Torres for this important info, I have added it to the answer!

Answer (score 3):

To add to the above answer, you may also use librosa function
`librosa.get_duration(y,sr)` to get the duration of the audio file in seconds.
Or you may use `len(y)/sr` to get the audio file duration in seconds